# Placing an image under a transparent object won't reflect in it

Tags: image, transparency

So I'm basically placing a sample poster under some transparent dominoes I created. First I had a normal plane under the objects to see the transparent effect but when I placed an image (I imported it as a plane) the grey blender background only reflects in the dominoes. I feel like there is a simple solution to this but I'm new to blender and hoping someone can help me out!
[image: Normal plane vs. Image plane]

Comment: What render engine are you using?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I'm using eevee